# How restrict line numbering to a specific area

Tags: vim

I know in vim there is `set nu` for setting line numbering on all lines. However I'd like to know if there's a way in `~/.vimrc` to setup showing line numbers for the current line, as well as `x` lines before and `x` lines after. As an example:

```
  blah
  blah
  blah
4 blah
5 blah
6 blah <- current line
7 blah
8 blah
  blah
  blah
  blah
```

I don't mind plugin installation either if that's necessary to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But...why?! This is not possible with built-in stuff, but the [RltvNmbr.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351) implements relative numbering with the *signs* feature. You could probably modify the plugin to achieve what you want. But again...why?!

Comment: Because that's the way I'd like to view files and the point of vim is to be an editor that allows customization to fit one's needs. I will take a look at the plugin you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want relative line numbering,  you can do it also without plugin:

set rnu